# CSS Position Element Relative to Specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I have an existing table of fields wrapped in DIV classes:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
```

Imagine a table with two rows and 4 columns wrapped in div classes that match their positions. I need to move 3, 4, 7, 8 below the current table like this:

```
 1  2 
 5  6  
 3  4  7  8
```

What would be the best method to implement this (CSS, Javascript, etc)?

**EDIT**: Here's some code for all to see...

```
<table>

  <tbody>
          <tr class="row-1 row-first">
                  <td class="col-1 col-first 1-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test1">Test 1</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image1.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-2 2-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test2">Test 2</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image2.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-3 3-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test3">Test 3</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image3.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-4 col-last 4-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test4">Test 4</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image4.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="row-2">
                  <td class="col-1 col-first 5-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test5">Test 5</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image5.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-2 6-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test6">Test 6</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image6.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-3 7-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test7">Test 7</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image7.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-4 col-last 8-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test8">Test 8</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image8.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="row-3 row-last">
                  <td class="col-1 col-first 9-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test9">Test 9</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image9.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-2 10-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test10">Test 10</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image10.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-3 11-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test11">Test 11</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image11.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-4 col-last 12-classed">

  <div>        <span class="field-content"><a href="/test12">Test 12</a></span>  </div>  
  <div>        <span class="field-content"><img src="image12.jpg" width="50" height="50"></span>  </div>          </td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried already.

Comment: Use JS to save status to an array and then swap rows and columns as you whish

Comment: Could you please post html code? it will be easier to help you if we can see the actual arrangements you want (initial and final).

Comment: Just in case anybody didn't follow this...this is a dynamically-generated table. I can manipulate the output in anyway but I just need space on row 1 and row 2.

Answer (score 0):

So...I ended up using tables to accomplish this. I was so stuck on DIV coding and I got a wake-up call after reading a couple of forums. This is tabular data and should be represented in a table.

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid red">
<tr><td>
    <h3>Title</h3>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td align=center>1</td>
 <td align=center>2</td>
 <td align=center>3</td>
 <td rowspan=2 align=center>4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td align=center>5</td>
 <td align=center>6</td>
 <td align=center>7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td align=center>8</td>
 <td align=center>9</td>
 <td align=center>10</td>
 <td align=center>11</td>
</tr>

</table>
```